# Outlook 2016 Remove Default Account

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, imap, microsoft-office-2016

I setup MS outlook 2016 (from an office 365 install) on a colleagues PC. I mistakenly set it up as POP3 instead of IMAP.

I added another account, IMAP this time & removed the default account from Account Settings > Email Accounts.

The problem is the default account still appears in the folder pane & I am unable to delete it.

Help appreciated.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

1. Close Outlook.
2. Run Windows Control Panel.
3. Open the "Mail (Microsoft Outlook 2016)" applet and click the "Show Profiles..." button.
4. Remove the existing "Outlook" profile.
5. Add a new profile, name it "Outlook" and create a new account as needed.

Comment: Excellent, many thanks for the soltion, worked a treat